# OSX : Read-only external HDD

Tags: macos, permissions, external-hard-drive

I recently moved from my old Win10 laptop to a macbook pro running El Capitan. I also moved from France to the UK without my old laptop.

I'm trying to use my external hdd to store data, but I can't write anything to it as it's in read-only mode. I looked online and all the solutions I found required to click the lock in the drive information window (e.g. https://www.cnet.com/news/solving-read-only-conditions-for-external-hard-drives/), but this lock is missing.

Obviously chmod -RN doesn't work as it's read only.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably your Windows drive is formatted as NTFS - Mac by default can read but not write to NTFS drives.

There are hacky ways to enable it from Terminal, or by installing MacFuse & NTFS-3G, none of which I've found satisfying or reliable.

The reliable way to do it is to purchase [Paragon NTFS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac) [17 USD]
[no affiliation.]

Once you've enable write, then permissions are no longer an issue, for any drive other than your boot drive you can Get Info & set "ignore ownership" for the entire volume.

Alternatively, if you've backed up the data elsewhere, you can just format it in Disk Utility. Select GUID/HFS+ as the optimal structure for Mac, MBR/ExFAT for portability to other OSes.